Question about positive and negative variation: passage to the supremum
Let $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded variation function and we denote with $\Pi$ the collection of all partitions of the interval $[a,b]$. Let $\Delta\in \Pi$ Let's introduce introduce three quantities $$t_{ab}(f,\Delta):=\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\rvert$$
$$p_{ab}(f,\Delta):=\sum_{k=1}^n[f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})]_+$$
$$n_{ab}(f,\Delta):=\sum_{k=1}^n[f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})]_{-}$$
Now let's define $$T_{ab}(f):=\sup_{\Delta\in \Pi}t_{ab}(f,\Delta)$$
$$P_{ab}(f):=\sup_{\Delta\in \Pi}p_{ab}(f,\Delta)$$
$$N_{ab}(f):=\sup_{\Delta\in \Pi}n_{ab}(f,\Delta)$$
It's simple to prove that $$p_{ab}(f,\Delta)+n_{ab}(f,\Delta)=t_{ab}(f,\Delta)\tag1$$
and
$$p_{ab}(f,\Delta)-n_{ab}(f,\Delta)=f(b)-f(a)\tag2$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain that $$p_{ab}(f,\Delta)=\frac{1}{2}t_{ab}(f,\Delta)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2}\tag3$$
and
$$n_{ab}(f,\Delta)=\frac{1}{2}t_{ab}(f,\Delta)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2}\tag4$$

Is it formally correct to pass to the supremum on all partitions $\Delta$ of $[a,b]$ in $(3)$ and in $(4)$ to get $$P_{ab}(f)=\frac{1}{2}T_{ab}(f)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2}$$ and $$N_{ab}(f)=\frac{1}{2}T_{ab}(f)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2}$$

